# macOS Sierra: Safari dialog opens with no buttons

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, safari, dialog

Whenever I open safari, this alert opens with no buttons. The only way to close it is to force quit safari. How can I fix this?

[image: Photo]

MacOS 10.12.4
MacBook Air 2013

Answer (score 1):

Make sure Safari is closed when preforming this operation.

1. Go to `~/Library/Safari/`
2. Drag the `Bookmarks.plist` to your `Desktop`
3. Move all other files and folders in `~/Library/Safari/` into your trash
4. Open Safari and then immediately quit out
5. Replace the `Bookmarks.plist` in `~/Library/Safari/` with the `Bookmarks.plist` that you saved on your `Desktop` in step 2
6. Open Safari and see if the problem persists